# ssis c# script task: 'else' can't catch the correct status for window services

Tags: c#, ssis, windows-services

I need to use ssis c# script task to check if the service 'AutomationServices' is running on several remote servers (return value of the variable is written to database table). I have the below code, but status shows 'Running' for all servers, even for servers where the service is not running. Why the 'else' part doesn't work?

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "AutomationServices";
sc.MachineName = Dts.Variables["User::Server"].Value.ToString();

if (sc.Status == ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    Dts.Variables["User::ServiceStatus"].Value = "Running";
}
else 
{
    Dts.Variables["User::ServiceStatus"].Value = "NotRunning";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried to just pass the servicecontroller status to the dts variable to avoid using 'if else', but nothing is passed, the status field is empty in the table, what is missing here? why it doesn't pass the status value ('Running', 'Stopped', etc) to the variable?

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "AutomationServices";
sc.MachineName = Dts.Variables["User::Server"].Value.ToString();

if (sc.Status != null)
        {
        Dts.Variables["User::ServiceStatus"].Value = sc.Status.ToString();
        }
```